# Html page not working on Mac

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, submenu, tidesdk

THe following script is working on firefox(windows). I have to test it also on tide sdk, beause  have to do a small application, but is not working. The problem is that the sub menu is visible without the click while on windows firefox is working right, I have to click the item and then I can see( if there is one or more) the submenu.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 


<script>
$(function(){

   //Hide all the sub menus
   $('.sub-menu').hide();

   $("li:has(ul)").click(function(){
      //Find the child ul and slideToggle
      $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
   });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

So, why is happening this?

Comment: Did you try looking at the console? Any error? Issue?

Comment: Use `http://ajax` for both script tags when working locally otherwise it tries to find the files on your computer.

Comment: Working for me on a mac (http://jsbin.com/ivavis/1/edit). Maybe it doesn't work on your actual code because there you have real `href` attributes? You're not preventing the default event on click, so it should just navigate away instead of toggling the submenus.

Comment: thanks @Joe you were right!!